# Does dbDelta delete columns as well?

Tags: database, wpdb, dbdelta

I created a table using the dbDelta function and then removed a few columns and added a few. The new columns did get created but the old columns did not get deleted from the table.

Is there a different way I am supposed to delete columns from the table ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, `dbDelta()` is primarily used to add tables to the database. It can also add  or alter columns. To delete columns, you should use `$wpdb->query()`:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_name';
$wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE $table DROP COLUMN column_name" );
```

Comment: Not correct.  dbDelta can, and does add columns.

Comment: Sorry, @cale_b, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 11):

No, dbDelta can add or alter columns, but not drop them.

The code for the dbDelta function is in wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php. You can examine what it is capable of there.