# dbDelta ALTER TABLE syntax?

Tags: plugin-development, dbdelta

Due to some changes in the DB, I need to alter a table to add one column to it, but even though the function is running, the table isn't altered.
Here's the ALTER TABLE code that I've written

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $packagetable . " ADD COLUMN price decimal(14,2) NOT NULL AFTER description;";
dbDelta($sql);
```

I couldn't find the syntax for ALTER TABLE with dbDelta anywhere online. 
EDIT: After looking at the ALTER TABLE statement in gravity forms plugin, I have updated the statement in single line.

Comment: The syntax is the same as general MySQL syntax, therefore this question is not specific to WordPress. Google the correct syntax for an `ALTER TABLE` command

Comment: The MySQL query is correct. The problem is on dbDelta front. Thus, it is a wordpress query. I have tried the command in MySQL console by myself before posting it here.

Answer (score 17):

You've used the `dbDelta` function incorrectly.

The whole point of that function is you pass in a table creation SQL command.

If the table doesn't exist, it creates it.

**If the table exists but doesn't match**, it's modified until it matches. This includes adding and updating columns, indexes, and other aspects.

So what you want to do is run dbDelta, and provide it with your table **creation** sql, not table **alteration** sql.

[See here for the Codex' take on adding an upgrade/alteration to a table using `dbDelta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Adding_an_Upgrade_Function)

But it goes further! dbDelta is a picky function, you can't just put any SQL statement in there, it has to be formatted appropriately

Here's what the codex says on that same page:

> 1. You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
> 2. You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of  your primary key.
> 3. You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
> 4. You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.

And from another:

> ### dbDelta Function
>
> Like i mention before in one of my article, dbDelta function has the
> ability to examine the current table structure, compares it to the
> desired table structure, and either adds or modifies the table as
> necessary, so it can be very handy for updates of our plugin. However,
> unlike many WordPress function, dbDelta function is the most picky and
> troublesome one.  In order for dbDelta function to work, a few
> criteria will have to be met.
>
> 1. You have to put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
> 2. You have to have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the
>    definition of your primary key.
> 3. You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
>
> Well, the above criteria’s seem easy to achieve. But wait till it hits you.
>
> - http://hungred.com/how-to/wordpress-dbdelta-function/

Comment: `dbDelta()` *does* support adding and updating columns. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/76926/19726

Comment: I never said it didn't, I just said the way he went about it was incorrect. Use a create statement for the table you want, not an ALTER statement, and dbDelta will create the columns for you and modify the table until it matches what the SQL says

Comment: Okay, I get it. I never realized that you could do this with `dbDelta()`! +1

Comment: So, I updated the SQL statement to add the price column but got DB error that the table already exists. Here's the error message `WordPress database error: [Table 'wp_booking_packages' already exists]
CREATE TABLE wp_booking_packages( id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name text NOT NULL, description text NOT NULL, price decimal(14,2) NOT NULL, city1 text NOT NULL, city2 text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) )` and I checked in MySQL console that the column still doesn't exist.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details. If you can post any future code using a gist so I can see it in its entirety? Comments tend to ruin any formatting and newlines, which could make the difference between working and not working `dbDelta` here

Comment: http://gist.github.com if you're not aware of it

Comment: Here's a gist https://gist.github.com/4482802

Comment: @TomJNowell What if i had a field in my create table statement with data type text, now i wish to change the data type of that field to bigint, in this case the dbDelta fails. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: @IAmDhar how would I convert the word "banana" into a number? I would ask that as a brand new question, it's unlikely anybody has the answer though, and there's a good chance it is beyond dbDeltas capabilities ( dbDelta will change the column, it won't change the data itself )

Comment: @mehulved the problem here could be as simple as there being no space inbetween the table name and the opening bracket. dbDelta is extremely touchy about these things, make sure the SQL statement is well formatted and clean, even if in standard SQL a space isn't normally required etc, add it anyway

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, that there must be a space between the table name and the opening bracket. This piece of information just solved my issue with updating tables!

Answer (score 4):

To add column to some WP table in DB, you could use `$wpdb` for it:

```
global $wpdb;

$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `{$table}`
        ADD `new_column` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL;";

$query_result = $wpdb->query( $sql );
```

`$wpdb->query()` returns false if your query went wrong, according to [method's documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/). So you could write some if-else statement to do something on success or error:

```
if ( $query_result === false ){
    // error occurred
} else {
    // success
}
```

If you need add your new column after special column, just use `AFTER` in query:

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `{$table}`
        ADD `new_column` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL
        AFTER `exist_column`;";
```

Also, you could change

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `{$table}`
        MODIFY COLUMN `exist_column` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL;";
```

or drop column

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `{$table}`
        MODIFY COLUMN `exist_column`;";
```

Small tip: In PHP, inside double-quote (`"`), you could use variable in curly brackets (`"foo {$var} bar"`) or without them (`"foo $var bar"`) to input variable to string, instead of concatenation (`"foo " . $var . " bar"`). I use it in code above. Learn more about [string parsing in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: perhaps the answer from Tom is better suitable for the subject, this answer still useful for some scenarios. thanks!